# Match any 0-9 number with WinActive()

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, autohotkey, pcre

I have an AutoHotkey script which checks the active window title with `If WinActive("WFC-16 - Windows Internet Explorer")`

I need to change this to match any 2 digit number. I.E. `If WinActive("WFC-## - Windows Internet Explorer")`.

**Can I use RegEx-like modifiers to match any `0-9` number using [`WinActive()`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, I don't see a problem at all.

```
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
If WinActive("^WFC-\d\d - Windows Internet Explorer")
…
```

I'd recommend you to drop « - Windows Internet Explorer» suffix and add ahk_exe iexplore.exe instead, because different IE version have different names in the title.

```
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
If WinActive("^WFC-\d\d ahk_exe iexplore.exe")
…
```

An alternate approach, if it's hard to write specific rule for title match (or if the rule gets too complex), is to get title of active window and do any tests on it:

```
WinGetTitle wintitle, A
If (wintitle~="^WFC-\d\d") ; ~= is a shortcut for RegexMatch
…
```